# VS2010 - In Watch window variables are display in hex, but option "Hexadecimal Display" is unchecked

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, watch

I have the problem with "Watch" window in my Visual Studio 2010. Values are displayed as hexadecimal, but the option "Hexadecimal Display". What is more, when I break on same variable and I want to get the value of it's property (for example `e` is an exception and I want to see what is in `e.Message`) I get error "xxx does not exists". But when I use C++ syntax, the fields are accessible (see picture below). My solution/project uses C#. I think I changed something in the debugger settings but I have no idea what it was.

[image: Picture below]

**UPDATE**

I have another issue. When I stop on breakpoint and I want to see any local variable I get the message `error: identifier 'xxxx' out of scope`.

Comment: What you're seeing in the top row is probably e.ToString(), which could be doing its own thing.  Try adding a proper integer in your watch and see what you see in Value.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the top row. But I'm rather annoyed by the 2nd row, where Message is a proper string in the variable `e`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I would think all pointers (references) are displayed as hex no matter what. Try watching an int and see what happens. `e` is a reference to an Exception object.

Comment: No, it isn't any better. `e.Message` is a string and it should be seen in Watch.